# convert JSON to Excel in node

Tags: node.js, json, excel

I have a json response containing inner json content. I've added a library of json2xls and converted my json to excel. But, on the excel file in the address column, I'm getting [object object]. Is there any way where I could able to get those inner json value on excel?

```
var option = [{id: 1, name: "jason", address: [{city: "XYZ", state: "ABC"}]}]
    var json2xls = require('json2xls');

        var xls = json2xls(option);  
            fs.writeFileSync('data-report.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: Yea Sure I've posted my code if it's helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Problem with address property in json you cant keep it that way Try putting it as address_city and address_state property